# How do we create a Matrix Mat which have dimension N x M using Python taking values from user at runtime

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I want to have a Matrix of order N X M, in which:-

Each of next N lines contains M numbers denoting Mat matrix.
I implemented this:-

```
 Mat =[[],[]]
 M = int(input())
 N = int(input())
 for i in range(0,N):
     for j in range(0,M):
         Mat[i][j] = int(input())
```

But this Generate the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ust.py", line 19, in <module>
for i in range(0,N):
```

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

So question is how can I generate the Matrix so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get the error you do, which occurs when `N` is a string, rather than an integer. However, you have another problem.

You are not initialising a matrix with placeholders, and are trying to access indices in your matrix that don't exist because it is empty. As you are currently declaring your matrix, you'll need to either call `append`, or create placeholders like this:

```
M = int(input())
N = int(input())

Mat = [ [None] * M for _ in range(N) ]

 for i in range(0, N):
     for j in range(0, M):
         Mat[i][j] = int(input())
```

Comment: Your Answer is right I was implementing the matrix at global scope, that's why its not being initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Your Traceback does not match your implementation. I suspect you did run it without the int around input() for your dimension Variables.

There is another Problem with your implementation. You are not initializing the Matrix properly.

You can use

```
import numpy as np
M = int(input())
N = int(input())
Mat = np.zeros((M, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        Mat[i, j] = int(input())
```

Comment: Sir, This answer is also correct but as I import numpy I make my script little time consuming, though it is helpful in creating large size array at real time. Thankyou very much!!